# Solving nonlinear system with three equations and three variables

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations, nonlinear-system

Hope someone can help me with this:

> Solve the next nonlinear equations system over $\mathbb{R}$ $$ \left\{
>  \begin{array}{} x^2+y^2+z^2=6 \\  x^2-y^2+2z^2=2 \\  2x^2+y^2-z^2=3
>  \end{array} \right.  $$ Hint: Use auxiliary variables.

I tried to solve this using the hint like that:
$a = x^2, b = y^2, c = z^2$
Then the system become:
$$ \left\{
 \begin{array}{} a+b+c=6 \\  a-b+2c=2 \\  2a+b-c=3
 \end{array} \right.  $$
And there is one solution: $(1, 3, 2)$, but how to proceed from here?

Thanks in advance

Comment: becomes linear in $u=x^2, v = y^2, w = z^2$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiply the second equation by $2$, the third one by $3$ and subtract them from the first one. Then we obtain:
$$(x^2+y^2+z^2)-2(x^2-y^2+2z^2)-3(2x^2+y^2-z^2)=6-2\cdot2 -3\cdot 3$$
that is $-7x^2=-7$ or $x^2=1$ and we get $x=1$ or $x=-1$.

Can you take it from here? Finally you should obtain $8$ solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Set $a:=x^2$, $b:=y^2$, and $c:=z^2$. Then the system becomes
$$
\begin{cases}
a+b+c &= 6 \\
a-b+2c &= 2 \\
2a+b-c &= 3.
\end{cases}
$$

Solving this system yields $(a,b,c)=(1,3,2)$. Hence we have the equations
$$ x^2=1, \quad y^2=3, \quad z^2=2.$$
From these we deduce $x=\pm 1$, $y=\pm\sqrt{3}$, and $z=\pm\sqrt{2}$. Consequently the solution set is
$$
\{
(1,\sqrt{3},\sqrt{2}), (1,\sqrt{3},-\sqrt{2}), (1,-\sqrt{3},\sqrt{2}), (1,-\sqrt{3},-\sqrt{2}),
(-1,\sqrt{3},\sqrt{2}), (-1,\sqrt{3},-\sqrt{2}), (-1,-\sqrt{3},\sqrt{2}), (-1,-\sqrt{3},-\sqrt{2})
\}.
$$
We could also write this set as
$$
\{(x,y,z) \mid x=\pm 1,\,y=\pm\sqrt{3},\,z=\pm\sqrt{2}\}
$$
or
$$
\{1,-1\}\times\{\sqrt{3},-\sqrt{3}\}\times\{\sqrt{2},-\sqrt{2}\}.
$$

Comment: The variables are independent of each other? How would you write the general solution?

Answer (score 0):

multiplying the first equation by $-1$ and adding to the second we get
$$-2y^2+z^2=-4$$ (I) multiplying the first by $-2$ and adding to the third we have
$$-y^2-3z^2=-9$$ (II)
and $-2\times$ (II)+(I) we have $$7z^2=14$$
can you finish?

Answer (score 0):

obs : that's not a non-linear equation. A non-linear would be if it involved both x^2 and x at the same time.